# Testing equivalence for exit status

Tags: shell, exit, portability

Are the following two command lists portably equivalent?

```
$foo; echo $? #(1)
```

and

```
$foo && echo 0 || echo $? #(2)
```

### Postscript

Consider the command `exit-status` defined so:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit "$1"
```

Does the POSIX standard forbid the following?

```
> exit-status 2 && echo "impossible branch"; echo $?
1
```

If not, then a POSIX-compliant shell could fail to equate the two uppermost command lists.  Which isn't quite the same thing as not being portable...

Comment: Since the command lines do not contain a `|` symbol they are not pipelines.

Comment: @Max: That's actually right.  I've called lists of commands/pipelines separated by && or || 'pipelines' for ages, though.  Do they have a proper name?

Comment: They are called 'command lists' - or if one only includes logical operators, you can call it 'logical expression' - see for example `bash(1)`

Comment: @maxschlepzig As long as you're quibbling, this is a pipeline that happens to have a single component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both command lines are portable. And both have the same effect.

Regarding the 2nd: In case `$foo` fails, `echo 0` is not evaluated, thus `echo $?` prints the exit status of the last command - i.e. `$foo`.

The logical operators are left-associative, i.e. the 2nd command line is equivalent to:

```
$ { $foo && echo 0 } || echo $?
```

(where the first `$` denotes the shell prompt)

[Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) standardizes command lists, operator associativity and so on.

Section 2.9.3 of [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) also specifies the exit status semantics of the && operator:

> Exit Status
>
> The exit status of an AND list shall be the exit status of the last command that is executed in the list.

Regarding your postscript: Yes, POSIX does not allow it.

Comment: This says what I think, but it doesn't help me see why it must be true.  Does it follow from the POSIX specs, or is there some shell semantics that can be applied to see this?

Comment: Yes, see [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), especially 2.9.3, which includes a 'AND Lists' paragraph and a following 'Exit Status' section.

Comment: I don't see anything in section 2.9 that says what the exit status of `cmd1 && cmd2` is when cmd1 has an exit status other than 0 or 1.  I'll add a bit to my question to expand on this.

Comment: @CharlesStewart, take a closer look - I updated the answer which now includes a direct quote from the referenced paragraph.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse. I was confused about command lists and completely misread that specification.  +1, clear and correct.